# Is a chattering noise normal with the Fuji X-E1 and 35mm F/1.4 lens?

Tags: troubleshooting, fujifilm, sound, fujifilm-xe1

Is it normal to hear chattering noise in Fuji 35mm 1.4 x-lens when half-pressing and releasing the shutter button? Kind of annoying when the lens has focusing noise. Using the latest firmware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is normal, even if a bit annoying. It's the aperture stopping down to meter. In the original firmware, the X-Pro 1 did this *all the time*, not just with the shutter half-pressed. If you're curious, more on the firmware update that addressed this [here](http://www.dpreview.com/news/2012/04/24/Fujifilm-X-Pro1-firmware-18mm-35mm-60mm); the X-E1 is newer and so shipped with that already in place.